# VB.NET how to assign value using loops

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to shorten one by one my code but I don't know how to. I am using VB.NET and had a little knowledge about it. This is the part of my code, Is there a way to shorten this using loops

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    mdp1 = 0
    mdp2 = 0
    mdp3 = 0
    mdp4 = 0
    mdp5 = 0
    mdp6 = 0
    mdp7 = 0
    mdp8 = 0
    mdp9 = 0
    mdp10 = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: A loop would only work here if those variables are in an enumerable structure.  Another option might be to take the code as-is and just abstract those 10 lines into a private function somewhere else in the class (or a public one in another class, depending on how the code is structured).  Then this highly visible event handler would just have a one-line call to a less visible helper function (with an intuitive name of some sort), which is a bit cleaner.

Comment: What `mdp` are? Variables? Controls? What for?

Comment: Where are declared these variables? Are global variables for this form Instance?

Comment: They are declared as Private

Comment: Why not declare an array instead of 10 separate variables?

Comment: They are declared as private, but they are globals for the current form instance, so they are already initialized with zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change this to an array, all you need is this.

`Private mpd(9) as Integer`

All of the values will initialize (using VB). Note that .Net is 0 based, thus to access the 10th member, it would be mpd(9). The first value would be mpd(0) not mpd(1).

Comment: Your declaration declares an array of 11 integers, not 10.  In VB.Net, the array is declared with the upper bound not the size.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jim's answer, here is some code to help you, I am unsure if this will answer your entire question fully:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

      Dim mdp() As Integer = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
 End Sub
```

Comment: Your first part of the example does not work: Explicit initialization is not permitted for arrays declared with explicit bounds.